# How does react handle props changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Note that this happened in `react-native` but probably happens in `React` too.

While coding i found myself lost when I was trying to use a `this.props` reference that was initialized in the `constructor`. For example:

```
class PropsComponent extendes Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.constructorProps = this.props;
   }

   render(){ 
      return null 
   }
}
```

A sample parent would be:

```
class Parent extends Component {

   ...

   render(){ 
      return (
          <PropsComponent dummyProp = {this.state.dummyPropToPass} />
          <Button onPress{() => this.setState ({dummyPropToPass : "Dummy 1"})} />
          <Button onPress{() => this.setState ({dummyPropToPass : "Dummy 2"})} />
          <Button onPress{() => this.setState ({dummyPropToPass : "Dummy 3"})} />
      )
   }
}
```

Now, if i try to log the `constructorProps` value and compare it with the `this.props` values, after an update, they are different.

```
//referred to the PropsComponent

componentDidMount = () => {
    //this.constructorProps are correctly displayed are are the same as this.props

    console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.props : ", this.props)
    console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.constructorProps : ", this.constructorProps)
}

componentDidUpdate = () => {

    //this.constructorProps has still the same props from the constructor 
    //while this.props is updated with the new dummyProp

    console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.props : ", this.props)
    console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.constructorProps : ", this.constructorProps)
}
```

From now on, no matter what button or how many times I press it, `this.constructorProps` will always have the initial `constructor` props.

To check if this only happened during `constructor` I modified the `componentDidUpdate` doing:

```
    componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if(prevProps.dummyProp === "initialDummyProp"){
        this.updatedProps = this.props
    }
    console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.props : ", this.props)
    console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.constructorProps : ", this.constructorProps)
    console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.updatedProps : ", this.updatedProps)
}
```

While changing the Parent with an initial state:

```
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           dummyPropToPass : "initialDummyProp"
       };   
   }

   render(){ ... }
}
```

The result were:

First Render

**DidMount:**

```
this.props.dummyProp = "initialDummyProp"
this.constructor.dummyProp = "initialDummyProp"
```

**Click on Button 1**

**didUpdate:**

```
this.props.dummyProp = "Dummy 1"
this.constructor.dummyProp = "initialDummyProp"
this.updatedProps.dummyProp = undefined
```

**Click on Button 2**

**didUpdate:**

```
this.props.dummyProp = "Dummy 2"
this.constructor.dummyProp = "initialDummyProp"
this.updatedProps.dummyProp = "Dummy 1"
```

**Click on Button 3**

**didUpdate:**

```
this.props.dummyProp = "Dummy 3"
this.constructor.dummyProp = "initialDummyProp"
this.updatedProps.dummyProp = "Dummy 1"
```

Can you explain what is actually happening here? Does the `this` reference change at every prop change or every render?

I'll leave the final components here:

**Child**

```
class PropsComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.constructorProps = this.props;
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.props : ", this.props);
        console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.constructorProps : ", this.constructorProps);
    };

    componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
        if (prevProps.dummyProp === "initialDummyProp") {
            this.updatedProps = this.props;
        }
        console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.props : ", this.props);
        console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.constructorProps : ", this.constructorProps);
        console.log("PropsComponent, componentDidMount, this.updatedProps : ", this.updatedProps);
    };

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           dummyPropToPass : "initialDummyProp"
       };   
   }
   render(){ 
      return (
          <PropsComponent dummyProp = {this.state.dummyPropToPass} />
          <Button onPress{() => this.setState ({dummyPropToPass : "Dummy 1"})} />
          <Button onPress{() => this.setState ({dummyPropToPass : "Dummy 2"})} />
          <Button onPress{() => this.setState ({dummyPropToPass : "Dummy 3"})} />
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: constructor is only called once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contructor` is only called once when the component to be mounted is initialized. It will not be called again during the lifetime of the component. If you modify the code like this:

```
<PropsComponent 
    key={this.state.dummyPropToPass} 
    dummyProp={this.state.dummyPropToPass}
/>
```

you will see that because react treats a component with a different `key` as a new component it will unmount the old one and construct a new one calling the `constructor` again.

Also your condition

```
if (prevProps.dummyProp === "initialDummyProp") {
    this.updatedProps = this.props;
}
```

will only be met during the first update which is why you only see `this.updatedProps` changing after the first button click.

**Working example:**

[image: Edit lingering-mountain-3rnw2]

Simply put imagine this would be an instance method of your component that gets called when it receives new props:

```
onNewPropsReceived = newProps => {
   const oldProps = this.props; 
   this.props = newProps;

   // rendering omitted

   this.componentDidUpdate(oldProps);
}
```

So `this.props` will now be pointing to the new object while `this.contructorProps` still points to the old object assigned in the `constructor`.

Note that this is not the actual code but it roughly illustrates what is happening.

Comment: The problem here is that in Javascript assigning a variable to an already existing object just creates a reference of that object inside the wanted one ( `a= {key : 1}`; `b=a` ; `a.key= 2` => b will end up being `{key: 2}` without directly touching it). This does not happen with the this.props object in react tho, I wanted to know what was actually happening behind the scenes. Why is this.props changing it's reference?

Comment: @Auticcat React does not mutate the old `props` object. Instead it will create a new object that reflects the changes. It literally does what is shown in the function in my answer where `newProps` is a new object. So `props` objects are immutable. So after an update `this.props` points to a completely different object.

Comment: @Auticcat Or simply put: After every render `this.props` will be a new object. React identifies a mounted component by its type and position. it will then re-render it passing the current props in a new object even when nothing in it changed. This is also why children by default re-render when the parent re-renders. Only a `PureComponent` compares the old and new props by doing a [shallow equal comparison](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-compare.html) of the properties and decides based on this if it should really re-render.

Comment: So specifically, is the `props` key value changing or the whole `this`?

Comment: @Auticcat Only the `props` value changes, `this` itself will point to the same component instance for the whole lifetime.